# System.js after execute hook

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, jspm, systemjs, es6-module-loader

In my project I have a lot of so-called javascript 'services', service has the following structure:

```
var serviceA = function(){
    this.init(); // service initialization code
    this.load = function(){
        return asyncLoadA(); // returns promise, for example service is asynchronously reading data
                             // required for it's work from file or webSql
    }
}

var serviceB = function(depA){
    this.init(depA.data);
    this.load = function(){
        return asyncLoadB(depA.data);
    }
}

var a = new serviceA(), b;
a.load().then(function(){
    b = new serviceB(a).load();
})
```

So, services are dependent on each other and have async load function, and dependent service can be created only when it's dependencies are loaded. Example above is a pure javascript, but can be easily rewritten as ES6 modules.

Is it possible to load such services via system.js plugin (I don't want to modify system.js library source)? All I need is to delay module execution until it's dependencies are not ready. It seems that instantiate hook is not good for it because I still want standard ES6 linking and execution to work.

Comment: What do you mean by *you do not want to modify system.js library source*?
I assume you can hand in pull-requests, but for what?

Just to be clear: SystemJS is a dynamic module loader. Simple setup requires setting up a config file. 
There is also an API to import a module programmatically (https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/system-api.md#systemimportmodulename--normalizedparentname---promisemodule).